# How to delete or rename files from inside the open dialog on OS X?

Tags: macos

By default I know that OS X does not allow you to do any modifications from inside the open dialog, like

- rename files
- move files
- delete files
- tag files/folders

Is it possible to tune the system in order to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Why not do all this in Finder? Check this animation for a useful way to locate your file in Finder, directly from *any* Document window and Open/Save dialog:

[image: Sorry for the boring novel]

I use this dozens of times every day.

Answer (score 0):

The [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/) add-on could help you out here. It offers a ton of additional features for the Open/Save dialog including favorites, file/folder renaming and deletion and access to metadata (tagging).